# Fail to install matplotlib in conda

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda, python-3.6

I tried to install `matplotlib` with: `conda install matplotlib`, but got this error:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>        - matplotlib
>        - python 3.6*

What do I supposed to deal with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some dependencies are out of date i think.

Try this comman instead:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing matplotlib using:

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

This is done under my current Anaconda virtual environment. Therefore, the pip I'm using corresponds to the python version in my virtual environment.